# Using Simple Exponential Smoothing to Forecast Time Series Data

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast timeseries sales data with simple exponential smoothing in python but when i try using the predict function on the fit it just repeats the same value for each specified interval. Any suggestions on how to get a proper forecast?

Timeseries seasonal data:
[image: Figure1]

Fit Code

```
fit4 = SimpleExpSmoothing(Holt_Data, initialization_method="heuristic").fit(
smoothing_level=0.8, optimized=False
)

fcast4 = fit4.forecast(3).rename(r"$\alpha=0.8$")
```

Fitted Plot:
[image: Figure2]

```
fit4.predict(start='2022-01-01',end='2023-01-01')
```

**Predicted Value Graph plot:**
[image: Figure3]